# Kafka configuration min.insync.replicas not working

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Its my early days in learning kafka. And I am checking out every kafka property/concept in my local machine.

So I came across this property `min.insync.replicas` and here is my understanding. Please correct me if I've misunderstood anything.

- Once a message is sent to a topic, the message must be written to at least `min.insync.replicas` number of followers.
- `min.insync.replicas` also includes the leader.
- If number of available live brokers( *indirectly, in sync replicas* )  are less than the specified `min.insync.replicas` , then producer will raise an exception failing to publish the message.

Following are the steps I followed to create the above scenario

1. Started 3 brokers in local with broker Ids 0, 1 and 2
2. created the topic ***insync*** and set `min.insync.replicas` to 2
   using the following command

`sudo ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic insync --config min.insync.replicas=2`

3. Describe the topic resulted in the following

> Topic:insync  PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:min.insync.replicas=2
>     Topic: insync   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 1,2,0

At this point, I made sure the property I've provided is picked by kafka

4. I started sending messages and consuming them from terminal using following command

   Producer: `./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic insync --producer.config ../config/producer.properties`

   Consumer:  `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic insync`

At this point, I was able to send and receive messages successfully.

5. Bought down 2 brokers (0 and 2) and described the topic and resulted in following

> Topic:insync  PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:min.insync.replicas=2
>     Topic: insync   Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 2,0,1 **Isr: 1**

At this point, the In Sync Replicas are just 1(**Isr: 1**)

Then I tried to produce the message and it worked. I was able to send messages from console-producer and I could see those messages in console consumer.

My Kafka version: *kafka_2.10-0.10.0.0*

following are the producer properties:

> bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
>
> compression.type=none
>
> batch.size=20
>
> acks=all

I expected the producer to fail with `NotEnoughReplicasException` as mentioned in [this](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/errors/NotEnoughReplicasException.html).

> public class NotEnoughReplicasException
>   extends RetriableException
>
> Number of insync replicas for the partition is lower than >min.insync.replicas

but it worked normally.

Am I missing something? How can I create the scenario?

***************  **EDIT**  **********************

Instead of producing the messages from console producer, I tried to generate messages from java code. This time, I got the expected exception in the kafka broker. Although I expected it in the producer (java code). As this experiment is raising more questions, I've posted  [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59019463/unexpected-behaviour-of-notenoughreplicasexception-with-min-insync-replicas).

Comment: Try adding `--property request-required-acks=2` to the console producer rather than put in the config file

Comment: ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic insync --config min.insync.replicas=2  

In above statement you have given partitions as 1. The partition should be in sync with number of brokers. Please try with this value as 3 or equal/less than  number of brokers(but not 1 to simulate for NotEnoughReplicasException exception)

Answer (score 1):

is acks set to "all"? if not, try setting it to all

Comment: Like I mentioned in the Original post, It is set to ***all***.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe that error is for transactional producer, you may need to add this config:

   transactional.id=TID-TEST
2. if still not working, please check your replicator factor and min insync isr for the internal topic: __transaction_state