# Unexpected behaviour of NotEnoughReplicasException with min.insync.replicas

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

This is a continuation of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780219/kafka-configuration-min-insync-replicas-not-working)

I was experimenting kafka's `min.insync.replicas` and here's the summary:

1. Setup 3 brokers in local, created a topic `insync` with `min.insync.replicas=2`.
2. Messages were produced by **kafka-console-producer** with `acks=all` and read by **kafka-console-consumer**
3. Bought down 2 brokers leaving just 1 `insync.replicas` and was expecting an exception in producer as [mentioned here](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/errors/NotEnoughReplicasException.html)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780219/kafka-configuration-min-insync-replicas-not-working)

But it never happened and producer was producing messages and consumer was reading them from console without any errors.(more details in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780219/kafka-configuration-min-insync-replicas-not-working))

Then, Instead of producing messages from **console-producer** , I wrote a java producer with same configurations as console producer and finally got the following exception.

> ERROR [Replica Manager on Broker 0]: Error processing append operation on partition insync-0 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotEnoughReplicasException: Number of insync replicas for partition [insync,0] is [ 1 ], below required minimum [ 2 ]

Although I expected it from the producer(java code), it showed up in the **kafka broker**.

**Console producer command**

```
 ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic insync --producer.config ../config/producer.properties
```

**kafka-console-producer properties:**

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094
compression.type=none
batch.size=20
acks=all
```

**Java producer code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(producerConfigs());

        try {

            int count = 0;
            while (true) {
                ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("insync",
                        "test message: " + count);
                kafkaProducer.send(record);

                Thread.sleep(3000);
                count++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            kafkaProducer.close();
        }
    }

    private static Properties producerConfigs() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094");
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        properties.put("acks", "all");

        return properties;
    }
```

This brings me more questions.

1. Why does it happen while running java producer and not in console-producer.?
2. Why does the exception occur in broker and not in producer(java code)?
   the  [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/errors/NotEnoughReplicasException.html)  for `min.insync.replicas` says

   > If this minimum cannot be met, then the producer will raise an exception (either NotEnoughReplicas or NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppend)

How does kafka guarantee reliability in this case?

Comment: As I commented before, `request-required-acks` on the console producer, not just `acks`. And do you have unclean leader election enabled?

Comment: Also can you share your producer code?

Comment: @cricket_007 I did yet it didn't work from producer. It seems `request-required-acks` is deprecated from `kafka 0.8`. Im using `kafka 0.10.0`. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-1+-+Remove+support+of+request.required.acks

Comment: It still exists in the console producer. It was only removed from the producer property constants https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleProducer.scala#L157 and if you're experimenting anyway, why not use the latest version?

Comment: @cricket_007 My organization is using `kafka 0.10` in production. So sticking to the same version :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When producing with `acks=all` to a topic that has less in-sync replicas than `min.insync.replicas`, the producer should get `NotEnoughReplicas`.

The reason why you are not seeing this behavior is because you have issues with both the console producer command and the Java code.

**1. Console Producer**

To enable `acks=all` in the `kafka-console-producer.sh`, you need to specify the `--request-required-acks` flag:

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 \
    --topic insync --request-required-acks all
```

This is because the `--request-required-acks` flag takes precedence over the values specified via `--producer.config` and it defaults to `1`.

**2. Java code**

The code you have pasted should be failing to send any messages but with the current logic you should only get `WARN` log messages like:

> Got error produce response with correlation id 15 on topic-partition , retrying ...

To get notified in your code, you need to check the result of `send()`, via either checking the `Future` it returns or passing a `Callback` as the 2nd argument. Not also that `NotEnoughReplicasException` is a retriable exception so with the latest client, by default, it will retry forever instead of notifying the calling code.

For example:

```java
Properties configs = new Properties();
configs.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
configs.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
configs.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
configs.put("retries", "5");
configs.put("acks", "all");

try (KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(configs)) {
    ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, "value");
    producer.send(record, (RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exc) -> {
        if (exc != null) {
            System.err.println(exc);
        }
    });
}
```

When the topic is below minimun ISR, the producer will retry 5 times before failing the record. It will then call the lambda with the exception, so you'll get:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotEnoughReplicasException: Messages are rejected since there are fewer in-sync replicas than required.

---

So to conclude, `min.insync.replicas` is handled correctly but you need to be careful to pass the correct arguments to the tool, handle exceptions correctly in Java logic.

Comment: Thanks @Mickael That seemed to work for java code. However, I get the following error message for your console producer command.  `Cannot parse argument 'all' of option request-required-acks`

Comment: Then you must be using a very old Kafka version. The ConsoleProducer tool has been supporting "all" since 0.10.1! In that case, set `request-required-acks` to `-1`

Comment: I have `kafka_2.10-0.10.0.0`. Yet, Im getting `WARN The configuration request-required-acks = -1 was supplied but isn't a known config.`